# C++ Class functions differently based on whether used in a QTConsole Application or QTWidget

Tags: c++, qt, recursion, heap-memory

I have a class , which creates a graph like structure on the heap and updates the nodes in the graph using a recursive function. When I use this class in a QT Widget Application , it behaves in a particular way , but when I use it as a console application , or when I compile it directly on linux it behaves in a different manner.

In both the QTApplication and Console I use the class in the same exact manner. And I have spend the entire day trying to find some reason for this, but no luck.

Does any one have a vague idea about why the program might behave differently [Generally] ? If you could give me some idea about what might be causing this , it would help me greatly.

PS. I apologize for not giving details , but the class is about 500+ lines and the makefiles are very large too , so I don't really know what would be relevant.

Comment: Is there any connection between the `class` and QT gui widgets' rendering function? How QT and the `class` is connected? Btw, use github or a similar website to share a gist, otherwise, our help can't be better than guesswork.

Comment: Yes there is , this class gets updated each time I call the advance() function , which is where I move the objects on the screen. Is there any reason why you ask about this specifically ? I am pulling my hair out and I have no idea what is happening.

Comment: I asked because I assumed that while rendering gui widgets, you are calling one or a few particular functions of the `class` which you don't call in your console application. This might happen but without seeing the code, I cannot tell more.

Comment: @MuratKarakuş Okay. Thank you. The hair pulling part about this , is that I call the exact same functions !

Comment: Can you show us main.cpp function where QApplication and your class are creating?